# IF statement returning the index value. But getting the error The truth value of a series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I am trying to form a print statement based on a Value in a data frame. Where the desired outcome is a statement such as;

'the days upon which there is a value is Jan3, Jan4'

an example of my df is as follows;

|  | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Jan2 | 0.0 |
| Jan3 | 0.5 |
| Jan4 | 0.5 |

what I tried was;

```
DaysWithValue = [] #an empty list
if df['Value'] > 0:
   DaysWithValue.append(df['Value'].index]

print('the days with value are;' + ' ' + DaysWithValue)
```

the issue being I get an error message of;

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

None of the a.___() worked, I want it to operate for each row not for an overall truth.

even if the IF statement had worked i'm unsure if the print statement would work with the list as its not string.

any advice on a simpler way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ['Jan 2', 'Jan 3', 'Jan 4'], "value": [0, 0.5, 0.4]})
dates_with_values = df[df['value'] > 0]['date'].tolist()
print(f"The dates with values: {', '.join(dates_with_values)}.")
```

Output:

`The dates with values: Jan 3, Jan 4.`

Comment: Nice answer. Could `df.filter()` also do the same thing? I was googling solutions before you posted your answers, and that's the guess I came up with. Slicing is probably nicest, but if filter works too, mentioning both would be helpful.

Comment: [`df.filter()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) "does not filter a dataframe on its contents[;] The filter is applied to the labels of the index".

Comment: OK, thanks. So slicing is *the* way to solve this, then. I came to that conclusion too, but thanks for the confirmation.